# After saving records multipicklist values are not visible and on the place of values its showing square brackets [ ]

Tags: visualforce

I am new to Vf pages, i have created a vf page which is containing custom multi select pick list, when i have select the values and save the record the values are visible on records but when i am again clicking on record's edit button and without making any changes to the record i am saving the record on the place of multi select pick list values square bracket is coming [].

Can anyone please help me with this.

```
<apex:page standardController="Contract_Database__c">
<apex:pageBlock mode="detail">
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" title="General Conditions">

<apex:outputPanel >
                <b><apex:outputLabel value="Non Standard Liablities :    " styleclass="labelFont" for="nonstandardliablities"/></b>
                <apex:outputField styleClass="picklistWidth" value="{!Contract_Database__c.uncapped_liabilities__c}" id="nonstandardliablities"/>
</apex:outputPanel >
```

[image]

Image which is having values:-

[image]

Comment: Could you at least post the markup that has the input as well?

Comment: please elaborate using the [edit] link and indicate relationship between standard buttons (new - edit - view) and all VF pages that may be overriding them

Comment: Hi Adrian, i have added the markup that has the input as well. Now could you please help me.

Comment: Your question is still unclear. Please add the mark up and apex code which is responsible for saving your record.